# Рекурсия в Си. (решение математической задачи)

Tags: c, рекурсия, факториал

мне нужно решить довольно простое уравнение с помощью рекурсии, но программа выдаёт значения меньше, чем должно было быть. Где-то сделал ошибку, но не могу найти, вот собственно условия и код(только рекурсия, больше программа нигде не работает с выражением):

[image: Пример]

```
long double rekyrsia (int n){

    long double sum, fct=1;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       fct=fct*i;
    if(n>1) {
            sum=rekyrsia(n-1.0);}
    return sqrtl(sum+(1.0/fct))*(1.0/3.0);}
```

Comment: Рекурсия идёт по индексу от единицы до **n**. Вы делаете наоборот.

Comment: Я начинаю с самого большого элемента, постепенно переходя в начало. Так же и надо, может я не до конца понял суть вашей мысли, укажите более конкретно, где ошибка, пожалуйста.

Comment: При начальном индексе **n** используется простой цикл без рекурсии. В вашей задачи нужна рекурсия, а там всё наоборот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неразумно считать факториал каждый раз сначала.

```
double recur(int n, int k = 1, double fac = 1.0) {
    if (k > n)
        return 0.0;
    fac /= k;
    return 1.0 / 3.0 * sqrt(fac + recur(n, k + 1, fac ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задача алгоритма должна быть такой : вычислить большую функцию с индексами от **a** до **b**.

Даю рекурсивную задачу : вычислить по индексам **a+1** .. **b**.

Выполняю свои вычисления по числу **a**. Используя результат рекурсивный (**a+1** .. **b**).

```
long double rekyrsia (int a , int n){

    long double sum, fct=1;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       fct=fct*i;

   if (a >= n) return sqrtl(1.0L/fct)/3.0L;

    sum = rekyrsia(a+1,n);

    return sqrtl((1.0L/fct)+sum)/3.0L;}
```